# Code that lists and inserts data to database: Make methods more reusable in superclass

Tags: java

I'm trying to make some methods more reusable and have now three classes that work together: AbstractDao (the superclass), MemberDao (extends AbstractDao) and ProjectTaskDao (extendsAbstractDao). The method insert is very similar in both subclasses with some minor differences:

insert method in MemberDao:

```
public void insert(Member member) throws SQLException {
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()){
    try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO members (member_name, email) values (?, ?)",
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
    )){
        statement.setString(1, member.getName());
        statement.setString(2, member.getEmail());
        statement.executeUpdate();

        try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            generatedKeys.next();
            member.setId(generatedKeys.getLong("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

insert method in ProjectTaskDao:

```
public void insert(ProjectTask task) throws SQLException {
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()){
    try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO project_tasks (task_name) values (?)",
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
    )){
        statement.setString(1, task.getName());
        statement.executeUpdate();

        try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            generatedKeys.next();
            task.setId(generatedKeys.getLong("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thesee methods do the same with some minor differences with the "statement.setSomething()". I`m not that advanced in Java yet so I'm kind of stuck on this. I would also like to pull these methods in as well:

list method in MemberDao:

```
public List<Member> list() throws SQLException {
List<Member>  members = new ArrayList<>();
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM members")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Member member = new Member();
                member.setName(rs.getString("member_name"));
                members.add(mapRow(rs));
            }
        }
    }
}
return members;
```

}

list method in ProjectTaskDao:

```
public List<ProjectTask> list() throws SQLException {
List<ProjectTask>  tasks = new ArrayList<>();
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project_tasks")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                //ProjectTask projectTask = new ProjectTask();
                //projectTask.setName(rs.getString(""));
                tasks.add(mapRow(rs));
            }
        }
    }
}
return tasks;
```

}

And here is the whole superclass as it stands currently:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T> {
protected final DataSource dataSource;

public AbstractDao(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

protected T retrieve(Long id, String sql) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    return mapRow(rs);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

protected abstract T mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
```

}

Let me know if you need more information to help! Thanks :D

Comment: Is your code working as you expect it to?

Comment: Yeah it works now, but wondering if it is possible to make it so i dont have to type the same method in every new classDao.java i make in the future.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @PetterHaugland Sorry about my downvote then (removed it now), I earlier got the impression that you have asked for a review of code that wasn't working.

Comment: First time posting here so im dont really know everything here yet ':)

Comment: @PetterHaugland It's alright, this community is typically very welcoming and you will find nice people here, I suggest you read [ask] for good questions!

Comment: Yeah thats good to hear! I will read up on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first advise is to not over-architect the classes.
2. Keep alternatives in mind - **JPA** for instance **eclipseLink**. A bit of not reinventing the wheel as the database field has a long history of "clever" code.

   This is an **O/R mapping** translating data base Relations into java Objects and vice versa. For a beginner I would first refrain from such magic, and continue as you did. (Your `mapRow`.)

   The entity classes like `Member` in general are kept small without logic.
   And for every entity class there is a repository class with data access (retrieve and such). They rely on a persistence manager singleton instance that takes care of the connection per transaction session (time doing some task).
3. A long ID and using generated keys is used often.

   For the ID inheritance can be used. Too much inheritance can be painful however.

So keep `id` in its own base class, and do

```
public class Member extends IdEntity { ... }

public void insert(Member member) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO members (member_name, email) values (?, ?)",
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            statement.setString(1, member.getName());
            statement.setString(2, member.getEmail());
            statement.executeUpdate();

            SQLUtils.fillGeneratedKeys(member, statement);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class SQLUtils {

    public static void fillGeneratedKeys(IdEntity entity, PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
        try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            generatedKeys.next();
            entity.setId(generatedKeys.getLong("id"));
        }
    }
```

3a. Similar is the initialisation of a time stamp field. If you disregard the database server's clock and use java's clock, think of a locale independent time.

4. Consider a "transaction" level; grouping of data base access.

   Several database operations, say some INSERTs and UPDATEs best function under the same connection. Possible as transaction, an error raising a rollback and otherwise the data is committed at the end. This cleans up the repetition of `try (Connection ...`.

In every case consider a *connection pool* or at least getting the connection by your own utility function.

5. For query methods do not use null results but `Optional` or exceptions. It not only prevents NullPointerExceptions, but allows chaining:

Several usage like:

```
A.retrieve().map(A::getChildren()).map(List::size).orElse(0);

protected Optional<T> retrieve(long id, String sql) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    return Optional.of(mapRow(rs)=;
                }
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here `Long` can be `long` (It is a `long id` field too). For retrieve-by-id an exception would probably be better.

Here it could be a painful use of inheritance as the child class provides logic; but it is okay.

```
protected abstract String retrieveByIdSQL();

public final T retrieveById(long id) throws SQLException {
    String sql = retrieveByIdSQL();
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    return mapRow(rs);
                }
                throw new SQLException(...);
            }
        }
    }
```

6. Consider translating an SQLException to your own child of a RuntimeException, by rethrowing catched exceptions. Checked exceptions like SQLException *must* be catched,
   which nowadays with Stream usage can be cumbersome. But you could postpone this for the fare future.

Comment: Wow thanks for your time there! Ill try it out and mark it as answered 

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! I have now figured it out and it works perfectly! :D